# Асинхронная загрузка изображений в UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostPreviewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSManagedObject *postObject = [self.postPreviewArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [postObject valueForKey:@"post_title"];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Комментариев: %@",
                                   [postObject valueForKey:@"post_date"],
                                   [postObject valueForKey:@"post_comments"]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        UIImage *postImage = [UIImage  imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[postObject valueForKey:@"post_imageurl"]]]];

        if (postImage) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                CGFloat widthScale = 60.f / postImage.size.width;
                CGFloat heightScale = 40.f / postImage.size.height;

                cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale);
                cell.imageView.image = postImage;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];

            });
        }
    });

    return cell;

}
```

Он загружает асинхронно картинки в ячейки. Как работает табличное представление, надеюсь, мы знаем, т.е. когда ячейка прячется за экраном, то эта же ячейка появляется с другой стороны экрана (в зависимости от свайпа вверх или вниз) и в ней заменяются данные относительно массива данных по индексу строки таблицы.
Так вот: когда появляется новая ячейка с данными, картинка остается старой и быстро заменяется на новую (т.е. относительно того же массива). Смысл в том, что это видно зрительно. Нужно использовать кеширование картинок. Вот в этом (для меня пока что) и проблема. Я не могу понять, как использовать это кеширование в моем коде. Перепробовал много примеров, но они для меня не подходят, так как в основном многие примеры используют свою модель представления данных.

`NSManagedObject *postObject = [self.postPreviewArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];` - объект со свойствами (в одной из которых хранится УРЛ картинки). Сам массив объектов формируется из кордаты.

Comment: если какой то ответ вам подошел (видимо ваш собственный), пожалуйста примите его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изобретайте велосипед заюзайте [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

> Asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an UIImageView category

**UPD**

Вот тут проще: [UIKit + AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking)

Comment: Спасибо, но хочу понять сам смысл, без сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Если Вы пройдете по ссылке, то увидите исходный код этой библиотеки, и я не вижу преград, чтобы изучить ее работу.

Answer (score 2):

В методе `Cell'а` сбрасывайте старую картинку

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

И в Вашем коде есть еще одна проблема.
Если картинки грузятся у Вас достаточно долго, и Вы быстро-быстро проматаете 20-30 cell'ов, то загрузка картинки начнется по 3-4 раза для каждого cell'а. 
И сначала появится первая, потом вторая, потом третья, потом четвертая.

Для того, чтобы этого не происходило, необходимо после загрузки проверять, а нужна ли эта картинка или уже другую просили загрузить в этот cell.
(т.е. в cell'е необходимо завести property с урлом картинки, которую мы грузим, и сравнивать).

Удачи

Comment: Спасибо. В принципе похожие примеры находил, но они у меня почему-то не работали.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем. Заменил диспатч на:

```
NSURL *imagePostURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[postObject valueForKey:@"post_imageurl"]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imagePostURL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        UIImage *postImage = [UIImage  imageWithData:data];

        CGFloat widthScale = 60.f / postImage.size.width;
        CGFloat heightScale = 40.f / postImage.size.height;

        cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale);
        cell.imageView.image = postImage;
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }];
```

делает ту же асинхронную загрузку + добавил плэйсхолдер.